# How to find something online when you only have a picture?

Tags: search

I have a chair that I have loved, but it is getting old. I want to get a new chair that is the exact same make and model. Unfortunately, there is absolutely no identifying information on the chair as to who the manufacturer is or where it even came from.

Is there a tool online or service I could utilize to find the origin of this chair?

[image]

Comment: Sometimes you'll find a patent number on an item you can use to find who made it, but often it's inside the plastic casing. Other than that being really descriptive (think "leather padded high back 5 leg gas lift chair with arm rests") can help, but you'll likely find it isn't made any more.

Comment: arms base and material look ikea. have you looked at the bottom of the chair for a label? I'd also note this dosen't feel remotely on topic to me, either as a chair ID or a chair ID method question ;p.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [google search by image](http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html).

> Google uses computer vision techniques to match your image to other images in the Google Images index and additional image collections. From those matches, we try to generate an accurate "best guess" text description of your image, as well as find other images that have the same content as your search image. Your search results page can show results for that text description as well as related images.

Nothing else to do really.

Answer (score 2):

[TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/) is the seminal reverse image search engine.

Unfortunately neither [TinEye](http://www.tineye.com/search/9e05b238e740bbb34537cf6773f93171d5879098/) nor [Google Image](http://images.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZis_1bP36D-pPdeCUPCPKADD9pJptCMO4GRedI-TQ39d-UpkTpE0C7XzraRhzn-vQ_1fDuR513_1aEJXtsNTAwkXnNVnIzUZGgLU-FmRl2UXJgYwV5nnKNoal-7UQccEBzTXd01jORq_1GryZugg2QaKEh2vOLNRkkPXGTjukkCvNDD-wZOla69hVD9rzRHzTuTGeYce8UEgPF-faz3ae9inr4Q5NKPLqEeyoc8ICYq3sM4QnRSbhGG4esnVBpO6L-aXr4O3-8MxW_1BUc1MiWQX5q7PO2xr0IwHTH6fu90M4pNhfzC0UuVBW38owYVVEZDs_1SyOJeFc40AslO8B7aBHpz9uhpcXCR8u3GVP4ossCA_115vsaEduQ1UFzT6W0P_1IlVphreOCy916hgf86_1IbxyD-KQzUG8jb2w5beCqFP8oeGKURy9OZFK0jFjQxf1eumO70Vb7qJaSMaR3iPM-nuqZUGaJsEZ3XfpPDyf9qC9xWyTEuqQT9uuM77a4uAoeXoVOEnvbAlJGEE2haNzEYc2vqDw8DfbhosT3Q84qrZq3oM5yxok8jOpcid5H7ZgAn_1AXuF8Gw7utNgl2iXOmd0jadKGkbmMvmJ6ZTewWQ63Rap_1v-N-PpbdRHmlKgRY-jnM4_19s4CVLxD0-7AV28B89Hr4kFpXsE9v38fgZ9ejk4sKPqkne3cJe_13rrD5oO7bPaYW9vNpGdsCkUNDdOq0JoHvzUVJ3Bl0QXJlixMDZeYKKQRi3SquPDfgQtLOEAvqaF9vI0ZWhTi8-BrCtclELIP8Rf12L3bDmU6gVsvv-6vgznT0x5j6mbDKFDVijAZySzvXV6yfhjBxEEjgZaVFpb59hkF6BYN-hJY8tzjAGPJKmYV7tiBuIYVR-grU0T_1yK810CJID66JD5PGqSbbqN9P0SmNr6RSY98XQ-v4lpEZnFK3kQPrCjQt_1-sUoft3B4DSod2gbOUTFrpJNHHxhcvfi1AZ340JuB4nuxaRtaH9lPMpBnOjKFKI-_1BCqDil9Dk3JvOd7HvHpxPmF5PzLjZp-44xzJt65imYV8qwWtQzABk6SFU01rX7dgDPjbhGY0HfdMJ7enh3v4c-iqU3zdSjCszkwXSRLYI1aibS9u3LIhc-FCj9gQ9pJ_1RlLvQkpazcsw_1TO02ucd868c2pCsok11k9j24J0NpVJvVr1boFCwXbZCMk1EXxpvZNYpLSiOac84HTWVIxrpeapBPPdplkjU0YSOLGwi9HLCiFj_1YG5onj-Co321Ay0lq7Sy7u8KD12K3OrJvd4WyBDSRCLYRkMYCPa4mRQ&num=10&hl=en&bih=383&biw=1022) seem to find anything with that particular photo (you may want to try again with another photo from a different angle and/or different lighting).

Comment: tineye finds the original location of images. As this is an image he made himself, I can't see how tineye will help ?

Comment: Define “original”. Perhaps originally, TinEye found the oldest page that happens to have the *identical* photo, but these days, it finds all images that are *similar*. For [example](http://www.tineye.com/search/53803716bbdeb8d8d6cc5cd138548580de00225f/?page=4&sort=score&order=desc), notice that they vary in size, the rating logo, and even the platform header. That’s why they need to try using different shots from different angles in the hopes of matching a product shot from a web site.